# Update the changes made in controller to the view

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

How to update the changes made in the controller to the view?

**View**

```
 Ext.define('SomeClassName',
 extends: 'Ext.container.Container',
 alias: 'widget.somewidget'
 /* other content here */
```

**Controller**

```
 requires: ['SomeClassName'],
 init: function(){
     var someVar = Ext.widget('somewidget');
     Ext.apply(someVar,{html: 'hello'});
 }
```

Eventhough, In the above controller, I am changing the `html` of the variable, the view is not changing. Am I doing something wrong here?

If this is not possible, then how to do this?

Comment: You're defining an instance of your widget, but you're not adding it to your viewport or any other container..

Comment: @Rob That's what exactly I thought.(I thought it will call inbuilt action in extjs). Anyway to update that changed variable to the view now?

Comment: `Ext.Viewport.add(someVar);`?

Comment: @Rob this will add to the viewport. (If I am right). The variable is nested in to many deep containers) and even the above code will not remove the previous existing view, I think.

Comment: No thats right, you will have to call `Ext.Viewport.remove(yourOtherViewInstance);` for that. But trust me, this isn't the way to go. Use like a tabbar or navigationview in your app. I have really bad experience adding/removing stuff directly to the viewport..

Comment: @Rob Before this, I tried `var someVar = Ext.getView('SomeClassName')` . resulting `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use `Ext.container.Container` if you just want to render custom HTML. `Ext.Component` will suffice for this. Second, you can use templates:

```
Ext.define('MyView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    alias: 'widget.myview',
    tpl: [
        '<div>Simon says: {command}</div>'
    ]
});

Ext.define('MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    requires: ['MyView'],
    init: function() {
        var cmp = Ext.widget('myview');
        cmp.update({
            command: 'jump!'
        });
    }
});
```

Note than `tpl` won't apply the first time component is rendered, you have to call `update` for that. To have the template rendered at initialization, set `data` property with default template values:

```
Ext.define('MyView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    alias: 'widget.myview',
    tpl: [
        '<div>Simon says: {command}</div>'
    ],
    data: {
        command: 'do nothing.'
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for this info. I will try this and let you know :). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What about that ([doc](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/api/Ext-method-widget))?

```
Ext.widget('somewidget', { html: 'hello' })
```

Comment: no, tried not working. Does this should work? I mean, will this code update the "View" ?

Comment: In a sense yes, but it is more accurate to say that it is an initialization.

Comment: Yes, I think this just creates a instance of the widget. but does not update the view to which it is given as `alias`.

Comment: It works for me : [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/EE9PZ/). I guess you have forgotten something, maybe `renderTo`?

Comment: hmm yes working fine in fiddle. Not sure why it hasn't worked for me in my project. may be because of MVC structure(I don't think so).

Comment: +1 I will try this again may be in future. Right now, I changed the complete code based on `itemId`'s and ComponentQuery's.  :)